# Phone link href="tel" shows up twice/double in Andoid phone

Tags: android, html, templates, hyperlink, phone-number

When the number is clicked, it is shown twice in the phone like this...

```
12345678910,12345678910
```

...instead of...

```
12345678910
```

Here's the code:

```js
{#if order.salesRep}
    <div class="info">
        <span>Sales rep:</span>
        {order.salesRep}

        {#if order.salesRepPhone}
            <a href="tel:{order.salesRepPhone}">
                <i class="fas fa-phone" />
            </a>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: View the final resulting HTML source. What appears there?

Comment: @ceejayoz Huh, why didn't I think of that xD. I assumed it's a browser problem, not a data problem, since the database has just one number. However, the HTML does have the two numbers... Weird, I will check what makes it so. Please provide this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: @SolomonUcko I managed to solve it. It was my fault. The SQL query had double columns, not double data... So the phone numbers came from an array. As for the templating engine, it's the Svelte framework.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. It was my fault.

The SQL query had double columns, not double data.